# Creating a 2D game on the X-Z plane instead of the X-Y plane in Unity, any adverse effects or challenges with this?

Tags: unity, 2d

After coming to the realization that some things I wish to do in a 2D RTS are easier to do on the X-Z plane instead of the default X-Y plane, I'm considering moving my game over to the other plane.

What I am wondering, past the scripting changes to accommodate the different plane, is what specific challenges will this cause for a 2D game (using 3d physics, not 2d physics)? I did a test and flipped some assets to the X-Z plane and things seemed to work just fine, though I am not sure what unique challenges I will end up facing are.

All our objects will have a 90 degree X-Axis rotation so that their sprites display.

Comment: What is making you choose one over the other? The differences are extremely minor and there really is no major reason why you should want to choose one over the other.

Comment: Path finding and steering plugins meant for the X-Z plane, Unity navmeshes don't work with the X-Y plane as far as I know.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Annoying as heck.

Comment: Definitely, current issue is getting sprites to display on that plane. I may just have to make a mesh and slap the sprites on top of the meshes.

Comment: Its really a poor limitation of the other software that it limits what coordinate system it works with.  You should be able to specify, and it should internally swizzle if needed or something :/  or you should be able to provide a coordinate conversion matrix or something!